# Proving that sum function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

So given is a continuous function $f:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, a subset $V=I\times I$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the function $F:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R},F(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$. I have to prove that $F$ is a continuous function. I thought I could use the sum rule of limits, so because $f$ is continuous it follows that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{y\to b}f(y)=f(b)$. If we combine these two limits we find that:
$$lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x)-f(y)=\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}f(x)-f(y)=f(a)-f(b),$$
hence we have proven that $F$ is continuous. However I am not completely sure if this proof is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b)\in I^{2}$. Then we want to prove that $F:I^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, that is to say,
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall(x,y)\in I^{2})(\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y) - f(a) + f(b)| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Once $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it is particularly continuous at $a\in I$ and $b\in I$.

This means that for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there corresponds $\delta_{1}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon/2$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta_{1}$. Similarly, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there corresponds $\delta_{2}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $|f(y) - f(b)| < \varepsilon/2$ whenever $|y - b| < \delta_{2}$.

Therefore for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| < \delta_{\varepsilon} & \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \leq \delta_{1}\\\\
|y - b| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \leq \delta_{2}
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a) - f(y) + f(b)|\\\\
& \leq |f(x) - f(a)| + |f(y) - f(b)| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much!! This has helped a lot

Comment: @Thimo-Louis you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Comment: I have one question for you, why does it follow that for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there correcsponds $\delta_{\varepsilon}=\text{min}\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ such that $||(x,y)-(a,b)||<\delta_{\varepsilon}\dots$ etc.?

Comment: @Thimo-Louis It is essentially the definition of continuity.

Comment: @Thimo-Louis Sorry, I made a mistake. I have corrected my answer. I think it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterium, you get
\begin{align*}
 |F(x_0, y_0) - F(x_1, y_1) &= |f(x_0) - f(y_0) - f(x_1) + f(y_1)|\\
 &\leq |f(x_0) - f(x_1)| + |f(y_1) - f(y_0)| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've completely overlooked this for some reason